# Why use "ButterKnife" in my app to bind callbacks to methods?

Tags: android, methods, view, callback, butterknife

In a sense of improvement, when should I Bind Android views and callbacks to fields and methods?   // http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: what is your way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when should I Bind Android views and callbacks to fields and methods

When you can. This lib reduces boilerplate code like `findViewById()` or `setOnClickListener()`. You will gain in readability too.

But like @Angelina said, ButterKnife is not useful in Kotlin

Comment: Perfect. Now, is this library commonly used, like as a best practice, even for purposes of obtaining Google's Android Development certificate? Or is it more like an underground time saver...

Comment: It is commonly used by the Android Java developers

Answer (score 1):

This library helps you to bind XML views with Java/Kotlin code. In Java, you need to do it by calling `findViewById` method. But `@BindView(id)` simplifies it and makes code easier to read. You can use it if your project is in Java. If you use Kotlin, all views are imported automatically, see https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/